# Manipulating String inside XML node

Tags: xml, xslt, text

I have a program that consumes pipe delimited data, converts internally into an XML document, applies necessary transformations and spits out data the same way it came in as pipe delimited

input data will look something like this

```
John|Doe|23|19970101||||
123456|State Farm|Insured
claim|Report Title\.br\\.br\SECTION_TITLE\.br\\.br\****Plain 
Text*****\.br\\.br\SECTION_TITLE\.br\\.br\******Plain Text*****\.br\\.br\*****Plain Text*****|
```

Internally, this will be converted to an xml document as follow

```
<message>
<person>
<firstname>John</firstname>
<lastname>Doe</lastname>
<dateOfBirth>19970101</dateOfBirth>
<x/>
<y/>
<z/>
</person>
<Insurance>
<PolicyNumber>123456</PolicyNumber>
<InsurerName>State Farm</InsurerName>
<x/>
<y/>
</Insurance>
<Documents>
<Type>claim</Type>
<Report>Report Title\.br\\.br\SECTION_TITLE\.br\\.br\****Plain 
Text*****\.br\\.br\SECTION_TITLE\.br\\.br\******Plain Text*****\.br\\.br\*****Plain Text*****</Report>
</Documents>
</message>
```

The receiving system is expecting the report string in the `<Report>` node to be formatted with html tags.Below is the full message with the `<Report>` node formatted with html tags

```
<message>
<person>
<firstname>John</firstname>
<lastname>Doe</lastname>
<dateOfBirth>19970101</dateOfBirth>
<x/>
<y/>
<z/>
</person>
<Insurance>
<PolicyNumber>123456</PolicyNumber>
<InsurerName>State Farm</InsurerName>
<x/>
<y/>
</Insurance>
<Documents>
<Type>claim</Type>
<Report>&lt;html&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;b&gt;&lt;u&gt;Report Title&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/b&gt; &lt;/p&gt; &lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt; &lt;b&gt;SECTION_TITLE&lt;/b&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;****Plain 
Text*****&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt; &lt;b&gt;SECTION_TITLE&lt;/b&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;******Plain Text*****&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;*****Plain Text*****&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;&lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;</Report>
</Documents>
</message>
```

The transformed XML Document will then convert as follow and send the expected output to the receiving system on the outbound.

```
John|Doe|23|19970101||||
123456|State Farm|Insured
claim|<html> <head>  </head> <body> <p> <b><u>Report Title</u></b> </p> <p align="left"> </p> <p align="left"> <b>SECTION_TITLE</b> </p> <p align="left"> *****Plain Text***** </p> <p align="left"> </p> <p align="left"> <b>SECTION_TITLE</b> </p> <p align="left"> *****Plain Text***** </p> <p align="left"> </p> <p align="left"> *****Plain Text******<b> </b> </p> </body> </html>|
```

Using XSLT, If I tokenize with the pattern '\.br\\.br\', assuming the first token is always the Report Title and SECTION_TITLE are keywords I can look up using the contains function....how do I then build the  node string and get my desired output? or is there a better way to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: It is not clear to me where the empty `<p align="left"> </p>` come from, nor whether the use of `<b><u>` is something to be inferred from the input data or some fixed output format you know you need to create. As for first building the HTML but then serializing it into the `Report` element, that would be possible for instance using XSLT 3 and the `serialize` XPath function. Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version does your system support or can you use?

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen for your response, I can only use XSLT 2.0 functions.

Comment: @MartinHonnen tags <b><u> are used against the Report Title only. <b> tag against Section Titles

Comment: With XSLT questions you should always say whether you have any constraints on the XSLT version used. Most things that are difficult with XSLT 1.0 will have an easy solution with XSLT 2.0 or 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your XML as the input and the wanted XML result with the escaped HTML markup as the result you could use XSLT 3 and the `serialize` function to serialize the result produced from a step like the one in the answer to your previous question:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Report">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="html-doc">
            <html>
                <head/>
                <body>
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\\.br\\\\.br\\')">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                                    <b><u><xsl:value-of select="."/></u></b>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="align" select="'left'"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </p>   
                    </xsl:for-each>         
                </body>
            </html>              
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="serialize($html-doc, map { 'method' : 'html', 'indent' : false(), 'include-content-type' : false() })"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvz or https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvz/1 where I used a CDATA section to able to read the serialization result more easily show the result an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 or later give.